# Not a statement, void type not allowed here error

Tags: java

```
   public static void printTable() {
        List<UAccounts> alldata = dataviewing();
        for (int i = 0; i < alldata.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println( alldata.get(i).getUserID()+"\t" 
                    + alldata.get(i).getUsername() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getForename() + "\t")
                    + alldata.get(i).getSurname() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getPassword() + "\t"
                    + alldata.get(i).getIsadmin();
        };
    }
```

Sorry I'm guessing this is probably an obvious fix but I'm very new to java and cant seem to figure it out. On the line that reads System.out.println( alldata.get(i).getUserID()+"\t" I am receiving a not a statement error as well as void type not allowed here. If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong and what i would need to change it to to make it work it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Other than missing the closing parentheses at the end of your print to console, you should consider creating a `toString()` method in your **UAccounts** class rather than using al those getter methods then you can just do: `for (UAccounts account : alldata) { System.out.println(account.toString()); }` which is a lot easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

In your print statement you have the closing parentheses wrong:

```
System.out.println( alldata.get(i).getUserID()+"\t" 
    + alldata.get(i).getUsername() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getForename() + "\t") // it is here
    + alldata.get(i).getSurname() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getPassword() + "\t"
    + alldata.get(i).getIsadmin(); // but should be here
```

You need to fix it like this

```
System.out.println( alldata.get(i).getUserID()+"\t" 
    + alldata.get(i).getUsername() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getForename() + "\t"
    + alldata.get(i).getSurname() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getPassword() + "\t"
    + alldata.get(i).getIsadmin());
```

Basically what you currently have is

```
System.out.println("some string") + "some other string";
```

`System.out.println("some string")` returns void (nothing) and you cannot append a string to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to:

```java
    public static void printTable() {
        List<UAccounts> alldata = dataviewing();
        for (int i = 0; i < alldata.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println( alldata.get(i).getUserID()+"\t" 
                    + alldata.get(i).getUsername() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getForename() + "\t"
                    + alldata.get(i).getSurname() + "\t" + alldata.get(i).getPassword() + "\t"
                    + alldata.get(i).getIsadmin());
        };
    }
```

Make sure paired chars match each other. You can use a plugin such as `Bracket pair colorization` to make it easy.